# SVG Animation with CSS and SVG mask

Tags: css, svg

I've started drawing a doughnut in SVG. <s>And for some reason my mask doesnt work when I animate the bigger circle.</s>(Bug on Chrome version 90.0.4430.212) I only plan to animate the bigger circle and not the whole SVG/Doughnut (I don't want the smaller circle to animate I only want the bigger circle to scale). How do you animate SVG elements with a mask?

https://codepen.io/markkkkkkk/pen/oNZWOOx

```css
#myCircle {
  animation-name: scaleKeyframe;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: 5px 5px;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

svg:hover #myCircle {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes scaleKeyframe {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 10">
  <mask id="myMask">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2" fill="black" />
  </mask>
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" mask="url(#myMask)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in Chrome/Blink.  It works fine in FF.  Please consider [reporting it to Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).  If you do, please post the bug link here for future readers.

Comment: I didn't think of it being a bug. But thanks, I've reported it in the page you provided. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1213310.

Comment: I would still appreciate an answer about animating the element only and keeping the mask steady. Thanks!

Comment: This issue seems to have been fixed in the latest Chrome (91.0.4472.77). Try updating.

Comment: Yup, bug is fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would still appreciate an answer about animating the element only and keeping the mask steady.

Just wrap your circle in a `<g>` element, then apply the mask to that instead.

```
<g mask="url(#myMask)">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" />
</g>
```

<strike>Unfortunately, the bug is affecting this as well.</strike> *Fixed in Chrome 91.0.4472.77*

```css
#myCircle {
  animation-name: scaleKeyframe;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  transform-origin: 5px 5px;
}

svg:hover #myCircle {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes scaleKeyframe {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 10">
  <mask id="myMask">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2" fill="black" />
  </mask>
  <g mask="url(#myMask)">
    <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Damn. I'm impressed. :O I didnt think of using another tag. But it does make sense to separate the mask and animation. THANK YOU!!